# Remove data from column with str_remove in a function

Tags: r

I have a `dataframe` that show some simple data as shown below. I'm using a function to get this tibble to make further calculations easier. **What I want to do is to filter away the (N) and (OA) that are shown in the Food column.** Supposedly by using `str_remove`.

The problem is that they are within brackets which make my efforts not that successful.

```
dataframe <- as.tibble{ 
dataframe %>%
arrange(Number)
}
```

`dataframe`

```
Number        Food               Country
1             Pizza  Hut  (N)    US
2             Hotdog             France
3             Beef               US
4             Steak  (OA)        Canada
5             Pasta              Pakistan
6             Bolognese          Argentina
7             Pizza Hut          GB
8             Beef               Australia
9             Steek  (N)         India
10            Rice               Spain
#With 275 more rows
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Base: `subset(dataframe, !grepl("\\((OA|N)\\)", Food))`. Dplyr: `filter(dataframe, !grepl("\\((OA|N)\\)", Food))`.